# Problem with user validation by httpBasic and jdbcAuthentication in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I checked the most of solutions from stackoverflow and also few official articles like: [spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/) i have finished small webapi based on **SpringBoot** and i want change security level from **inMemoryAuthentication** to **jdbcAuthentication** and i think my code is correct and i have no idea why still i have **401** response code in **Postman**.

***Here is my code:***

1.POM DEPENDENCIES

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2. DOMAIN CLASS API CLIENT

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "apiclient")
public class ApiClient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    @Size(max = 65)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "role")
    @Size(max = 15)
    private String role;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApiClient{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", role='" + role + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

3. REST CONTROLLER

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/user")
    public String showUserMsg() {
        return "User has logged in!!!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/admin")
    public String showAdminMsg() {
        return "Admin has logged in!!!";
    }
}
```

4. SECURITY CLASS

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**");
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, true"
                        + " from apiclient where username='?'")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role"
                        + " from apiclient where username='?'");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

5. COMMAND LINE RUNNER OF AUTO USER REGISTRATION

```java
public class SampleDataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        ApiClient user = new ApiClient();
        user.setRole("USER");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("TESTPAS123"));
        user.setUsername("USER");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();

        System.out.println(user);

        ApiClient admin = new ApiClient();
        admin.setRole("ADMIN");
        admin.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("TESTPAS123"));
        admin.setUsername("ADMIN");
        entityManager.persist(admin);
        entityManager.flush();

        System.out.println(admin);
    }
}
```

After start springboot application h2 database look like:
[image]

Comment: Please check your username and role query that should return only specific fields

Comment: you are storing password encrypted right?

Comment: yes like you see on ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query with single quote `username='?'` causing problem.

Modify

```java
 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
 {
     auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
             .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, true"
                 + " from apiclient where username='?'")
         .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role"
                 + " from apiclient where username='?'");
}
```

to

```java
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, true"
                    + " from apiclient where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role"
                    + " from apiclient where username=?");
}
```

After looking at your code shared from github link, 
In your project you have not enabled logs with level DEBUG.

After enabling DEBUG logs i noticed

```
DEBUG - Executing prepared SQL statement [select username, password, true from apiclient where username='?'] 
DEBUG - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource 
...
DEBUG - Caching SQL error codes for DataSource [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource@3bcd426c]: database product name is 'H2' 
DEBUG - Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '90008', will now try the fallback translator

...

DEBUG - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point 
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
```

Your query was failing to get usersByUsername (because of single quote in query) and authoritiesByUsername query was not fired due to exception, resulting spring-security to treat user as ROLE_ANONYMOUS and hence 401(Unauthorized)

If you want to see logs in STS/Eclipse console.
1. create logback.xml file under src/main/resources
2. Copy below code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <appender name="ALL_ROLLING_FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>..\logs\SMTH_Project.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%-40thread] %-5level{5} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC"
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="ALL_ROLLING_FILE" />
        <queueSize>1000000</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level{5} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Pawel did you try that?

Comment: no its not, i just created repository with files
https://github.com/PawelSzymanski89/BasicAuth

Comment: @Pawel Updated answer.