# Spring Security cannot redirect not-logged in user from home page to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a web server built in Spring Boot 1.2.6 with Spring Security 4.0.2.

It works perfectly if user visit https://test.test.com/login directly

But when a new user visits the home page https://test.test.com, I expect it to be redirected to https://test.test.com/login but instead it stays in https://test.test.com.

My code for SecurityConfig is

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ImportResource("classpath:acl-context.xml")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
      .disable()
      .headers()
      .frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").authenticated()
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
      .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login");

  }
}
```

How can I make this auto redirect works?

Comment: Sounds interesting, can you think over and update question. What can be the maximum information i can provide to get this resolved. Set logger level to **TRACE** and when a user tries to acccess `/` i mean `https://test.test.com` - will you provide logs for that scenario. Note  that clear logs before access and attach logs after access.

Comment: If you have problem in setting logger level refer my answer in link it describes how to set logger level(log setting  mentioned at the end of answer) https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895752/2825798

Comment: From your posted code, it should get redirected to login page. I don't see any mistakes. Sounds strange and interesting to me. If possible upload project to github and share link here.